# range of cells into several variables

Tags: excel, vba, iteration, range

There's this range, e.g., (A1:A10). I have to reference them, say, A1= r1, A2=r2 and so on. Given the processing time of using loop, the values under (A1:A10) have to be loaded before the loop gets activated.

At present, I'm using Range("A"&i).Value=r. But this formula gets inside the loop. I need to reference this cells (e.g., A1:A10) using variable r1, r2 and so on... outside the loop, in the hopes that this will improve calculating/performance time.

Comment: Are you asking about named ranges? Or just saving a cell reference into a variable? Or saving a range to a variable? It would probably help to see the code you are using.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What you need is an array. check [this](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
Sub Test()

    'Pass range values into array.
    Dim myArr As Variant
    myArr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
    
    'Loop through the array.
    Dim x As Long
    For x = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
        Debug.Print myArr(x, 1)
    Next x
    
End Sub
```